# How can I change text colour mid word in asciidoc syntax?

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I have the task of converting some documents to asciidoc format.

I have ONLY the asciidoc standard tools - I do NOT have access to any of the css sheets that asciidoctor uses to render my output.

I have a need to change colour of a word mid word.

Let's assume the word is RedNectar

I want the first three letters rendered in red, the last five in yellow

If I split the word and use `[red]#Red# [yellow]#Nectar#`

I get the right colours, but a space between them

[image]

But if I remove the space, `[red]#Red#[yellow]#Nectar#` it renders as:

[image]

[The yellow highlighting is simply the preview indicating a problem]

So what magic do I have to perform to get these two half-words to join?  In many cases, I have the same problem *between* words as wee, when I use the {nbsp} (non-breaking space) between words - it's now seen as a space at all and I strike the same kind of problem as you can see here - I HAVE a space between Red and Nectar - it's just a {nbsp} - and STILL doesn't render properly.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an [unconstrained formatting pair](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/text/troubleshoot-unconstrained-formatting/) for the second formatted word:

```
 [.red]#Red#[.yellow]##Nectar##
```